# Path does not exist: dbfs:/mnt/bronze/SalesLT/Address/Address.parquet

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

```
input_path='/mnt/bronze/SalesLT/Address/Address.parquet'

df = spark.read.format('parquet').load(input_path)
```

> Path does not exist: dbfs:/mnt/bronze/SalesLT/Address/Address.parquet

I checked everything thing with the path is correct

error

[image]

the file exists

[image]

i have mounted the bronze container

[image]

also this issue

[image]

Comment: That looks like a mounted path. If you're using databricks, has a location from data lake or blob storage been mounted to dbfs?

Comment: Yes I have mounted

Comment: @ARCrow i have edited the question  i have added images regarding the question please can you check

Comment: FYI [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) That said: (as the answer has pointed out): you have trailing whitespace in your paths (you should consider fixing your path names)

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna use the screenshots provided in the question description:
When the `mnt/bronze/SalesLT` is queried, this is the output:
[image]

For example, the name of Address folder, has trailing whitespaces, but when the content of the folder is queried, those whitespaces are not taken into account:
[image]

Add the whitespaces and everything should work fine.

Comment: Best to post as a comment - question should be closed, as it's not a programming issue but more of a "typo" type of thing.